# Concept that ONLY allows non-type template parameters that are members of certain namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++20, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I have a namespace `Bar` and a namespace `Bar::Inner` (declared within `Bar`).

```cpp
// Bar
namespace Bar {
    size_t num = 32;
    
    // Bar::Inner
    namespace Inner {
        size_t num = 4;
    };
};
```

Then, I have a variadic function template `foo`. This variadic template accepts non-type parameters of common type `T`.

However, I want the **non-type parameters** to HAVE TO be members of namespace `Bar`, but **NOT** members of namespace `Bar::Inner`.

```cpp
template<typename T, T ...Sz>
    requires MyConcept<T, Sz...>
auto foo()
{
    return (Sz + ...);
}
```

And I'd like to accomplish that using concepts, if possible.

```cpp
template<typename T, T ...Sz>
concept MyConcept = (/*Whatever goes here*/);
```

So, to sum it up, I basically need a concept that can allow the non-type template parameters only if they are members of namespace `Bar`, but **NOT** of namespace `Bar::Inner`.

Comment: I'm not sure namespace limits is a thing in C++.

Comment: @tadman Really? If so, will I need to replace the namespaces with classes or structs?

Comment: What I mean is that C++ is pretty "open", if it's defined in a header file you can use it, subject only to restrictions like `private` and `protected` for encapsulation purposes. There's no mechanism to disallow access to particular namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely possible to filter variables by namespace if you allow yourself to use some extensions.

You have to also know that you won't accept values anymore. This may be a big downside.

First, let's declare `fixed_string`, this is gonna be useful for compile time string manipulation:

```
template<std::size_t n>
struct fixed_string {
    constexpr fixed_string() = default;
    constexpr fixed_string(const char(&str)[n + 1]) noexcept {
        auto i = std::size_t{0};
        for (char const c : str) {
            _data[i++] = c;
        }
    }
    
    friend constexpr auto operator<=>(fixed_string const&, fixed_string const&) = default;
    
    [[nodiscard]]
    static constexpr auto size() noexcept -> std::size_t {
        return n;
    }
    
    constexpr auto data() const& noexcept {
        return _data;
    }
    
    constexpr auto data() & noexcept {
        return _data;
    }
    
    constexpr auto begin() const& noexcept -> char const* {
        return _data;
    }
    
    constexpr auto end() const& noexcept -> char const* {
        return _data + n;
    }
    
    constexpr auto begin() & noexcept -> char* {
        return _data;
    }
    
    constexpr auto end() & noexcept -> char* {
        return _data + n;
    }
    
    constexpr auto operator[](std::size_t index) noexcept {
        return _data[index];
    }

    constexpr auto starts_with(std::string_view str) {
        return std::string_view{_data, n}.starts_with(str);
    }
    
    char _data[n + 1];
};

template<std::size_t n>
fixed_string(char const(&)[n]) -> fixed_string<n - 1>;
```

Now that we have the basic, let's create a function that returns the qualified name of an object using a compiler extension. It's technically doable pretty portably if you use compiler specific extension and you dynamically filter the string so it returns only the name of the object.

```
template<auto& v>
constexpr auto name_of() -> std::string_view {
    constexpr auto size = std::string_view{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__}.size();
    constexpr auto drop_begin = "constexpr std::string_view name_of() [with auto& v = "sv.size();
    constexpr auto drop_end = "; std::string_view = std::basic_string_view<char>]"sv.size();
    return std::string_view{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__}.substr(drop_begin, size - drop_end - drop_begin);
}
```

Then, we can create a concept to only yield true of the qualified name starts with a particular string:

```
template<auto& v, fixed_string namesp>
concept in_namespace = name_of<v>().starts_with(std::string_view{namesp.data(), namesp.size()});
```

Now, you can write a function that only accepts objects from a particular namespace:

```
template<auto& v> requires in_namespace<v, "bar">
void im_clever();
```

To filter out the inner namespace you can do this:

```
template<auto& v>
concept in_bar_not_in_inner = in_namespace<v, "bar"> and not in_namespace<v, "bar::inner">;
```

[See my code running in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Mbx5nzj58)

Comment: Isn't `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` applicable to GCC only?

Comment: @Amolgorithm GCC and Clang, but it's possible to have a working version for MSVC too

Comment: MSVC uses `__FUNCSIG__`.

Answer (score 0):

Non-type template parameters are... values. Values do not belong to a *namespace*; they're just values. The constant expression `2` is exactly equivalent to any `constexpr` value that evaluates to the value `2`. There is no difference.

If you take an NTTP, you are saying that it can assume any value the user provides. A concept can restrict the actual values of such a parameter, but not the argument *expression* used to provide those values. That is, by the time a concept sees an NTTP, all information about *where it came from* has been lost.

That is, if some template `templ<2>` can work, any constant expression `expr` will work in place of `2` so long as it resolves to the value of `2`.